# Is there new functions on AS3 for development in the iPhone SDK for Flash?

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3

I'm developing iPhone app in Flash CS5 and I wondering if there is a new function in AS3 for specific applications on the iPhone apps, and wondering too if they are component like iPhone style buttons for flash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/fitc/introduction-to-iphone-sdk-for-flash-developers/

visit the above url..